# Differential forms as maps vs as differentials in differential equation

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I am following this introductory video on [differential forms](https://youtu.be/PaWj0WxUxGg?t=98) by Prof. Michael Penn. At [5:44](https://youtu.be/PaWj0WxUxGg?t=344), he defines the following linear map (which I guess is a differential form:

> $ \langle dx,dy\rangle(v) : T_p M \to \mathbb{R}^2 , \langle dx(v),dy(v)\rangle = \langle dx(v),dy(v)\rangle$

After his example at [8:17](https://youtu.be/PaWj0WxUxGg?t=497) involving calculation of tangent vector component of a parabola,  I could easily grasp the above definition as the idea that the map takes in the geometric tangent vector and spits out it's components with respect to a basis (I am guessing cartesian basis but he didn't mention explicitly).

Here comes the part I am confused, starting from [9:20](https://youtu.be/PaWj0WxUxGg?t=560) he equates the component functions of the above mentioned linear map evaluated a point to the tangent vector of parabola given by the parameterization $y=x^2$.

Symbolically, At a point $(a,a^2)$ the tangent vector is equated as:

$$\langle 1,2a\rangle = \langle dx(v) , dy(v)\rangle$$

And then he equates the components:

$$ 1=dx(v)$$

And,

$$ dy(v) = 2a(1) = 2adx(v)$$

Or,

$$ \frac{dy(v)}{dx(v)} = 2a$$

And states that the LHS is just the definition of derivative. In the beginning the prof notes that the expression is supposed to denote a linear map, now at the end it when both the map components evaluated are taken as a ratio, it turns out into in the derivative. Why is the differential form both a linear  map and a differential?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538719/differential-forms-without-derivatives