# Can we develop differential theory out of Euclidean spaces, just with the structure of topological groups?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

It is well known to all that we define the differential of the map $f:R^n\to R^m$ at $x$ to be the **linear map** $Df(x)$, which satisfies that
$$
f(x+h)-f(x)= Df(x)h+o(h)
$$
Now I think linear maps as morphisms from $R^n\to R^m$, in the category of topological groups. So I think it OK to define the differential of maps between topological groups, i.e.

**Definition:**

Suppose $G,H$ are topological groups, $f$ be a map from $G$ to $H$, we say $f$ is differentiable(maybe plus the phrase 'on the right') at $g\in G$ if there is a map $Df(g)\in Hom(G,H)$ satisfies
$$
f(gr)=f(g)[Df(g) r] o(r)
$$
where $o(r)$ still means $o(r)$ passes to $e_{H}$ when $r$ passes to $e_{G}$, in their corresponding topology.

Although this definition is at least formally natural, I can not judge whether it is meaningful. Indeed, I came up with clues that in general case this definition leads to too much limits.

Firstly, It is natural to consider things(I call them group-folds?) like manifolds, if we care about things locally like Lie groups, their underlying topology are compatible with their manifold structure, so the lie-group-folds are still manifolds, nothing new happens.

As to the maps, take torus as an example, their automorphisms are discrete, as a result, the differentiable maps  played between themselves have to be group homomorphisms. This is not interesting too.

Moreover, I do not know whether there is natural topology on Homomorphisms, this is also a trouble preventing us from defining $C1$ maps.

But I also feel that maps like this behave somewhat properly to illustrate the symmetry of topological groups.

So I wonder under which case this definition may be interesting? Or it is just a boring generalization?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4375527/169085

Comment: More specifically, your construction requires that the "infinitesimal models" for $G$ and $H$ be equal to $G$ and $H$, respectively. Standard differential map as well as Lie theory use the Lie algebras of the groups involved as the infinitesimal models; whereas CC geometry a discussion of which is linked above uses certain Carnot groups ( = graded nilpotent groups whose first degree part generates the totality of the group).

Comment: In another direction, one can interpret differentiable maps as "approximately linear" maps; in this sense an object that proved to be very useful is a so-called quasi-morphism. See e.g. Kotschick's "What is a Quasi-morphism?" https://www.ams.org/notices/200402/what-is.pdf or Ghys' "Groups Acting on the Circle" https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/groupscircle.pdf .

Comment: Your definition doesn't uniquely determine the "derivative" of a map between groups, since you haven't articulate the requirement that $o(r)$ be a "smaller than linear" function of $r$. The standard definition of the derivative doesn't just make use of the *vector space* structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it also uses the *topology* via the existence and equivalence of norms.

Comment: Try to find nontrivial examples where your definition applies, say, in the case $G=SL(2,{\mathbb R})$ or $G=SO(3)$. If you can, then you are onto something. If you cannot, maybe this is just a useless generalization of the standard definition.

Comment: @Kajelad Nice answer, you hit my question itself critically. I have ignored the well definition, thanks!

Comment: @AlpUzman Thank you for your answer! The references really give me some insight.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Although Kajelad's answer proved this definition is not valid for too general cases, Lie groups still seems to survive for its original manifold structure, so I can still have a trial.  But it is awkward that I am not familiar with lie groups. I will try to learn more and take your suggestion. Thanks for your answer!