# Is there a sense in which a function converges to its total derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, topological-vector-spaces, frechet-derivative

In short: **Is there a way to rigorously define the total derivative (of $F$ at $x$) as a function $dF_x$ which is (1) linear and (2) a usual topological limit of some function $\mu:X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces?**

---

**Motivation:** Let $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$. The total derivative of $F$ at $x\in\mathbb R^n$ is defined as the linear map $dF_x:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ such that

$$\lim_{v\to0}\frac{\|F(x+v)-F(x)-(dF_x)v\|}{\|v\|}=0,$$

if such a linear map exists. This definition makes sense, but it is a bit indirect. The idea is that $F$ looks more and more like $dF_x$ near $x$, so it seems that the more natural definition should be something like $\lim_{v\to0} F(x+v)-F(x)=(dF_x)v$. The following points are suggestive:

- Normally when $\lim_{x\to c}\|f(x)-L\|=0$, this can be formulated as $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$.
- The division by $\|v\|$ in the above definition is highly reminiscent of the [operator norm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Operator_norm).

I don't think there is any trouble extending the notion of operator norm to general continuous functions (although it may be infinite), via $\|F\|_\text{op}=\sup_{0\neq v\in\operatorname{dom}(F)}\frac{\|F(v)\|}{\|v\|}.$ Then, defining $\hat F_x(v)=F(x+v)-F(x)$ , we might be able to manipulate the first definition into something like

$$\lim_{v\to0}\hat F_x(v)=dF_x,$$

where it is understood that the limit is with respect to the operator norm. Or rather, as we look at $F$ restricted to smaller neighborhoods of $x$, the operator norm of $\hat F_x-dF_x$ *restricted to this neighborhood* approaches $0$. $F$ would approach many functions in this sense (including itself, for example), but the derivative would be the only *linear* function it approaches in this sense.

However, when I try making this rigorous, I run into some challenges. Topologically, the limit of a function $F$ near $x$ must be a value in the range of $F$, not a function with the same domain and range of $F$; so this formulation will require speaking of the limit of some function besides $F$, probably mapping into function spaces or spaces of germs of functions near $x$. This is where my knowledge gets more limited and I hit a wall.

---

**Update:** Here's my current progress. Let $C^0_x=\{f\in C^0(U,\mathbb R^m)\,|\,U\text{ is a neighborhood of }x\}$. Define function addition/subtraction on $C^0_x$ as usual function addition/subtraction restricted to the intersection of both functions' domains. Topologize this space using the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{t\in\operatorname{dom}(f-g)\setminus\{x\}}\frac{\|f(t)-g(t)\|}{\|t-x\|}$. This metric can take infinite values, but this seems ok according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399722/metric-assuming-the-value-infinity). Finally, let $\mu_{x,F}:(0,\infty)\to C^0_x$ be defined by $\mu_{x,F}(\delta)=F\big|_{B_\delta(x)}$. Then, perhaps, we can define $dF_x$ (if it exists) as the unique linear map defined on all of $\mathbb R^n$ such that

$$\lim_{\delta\to0}\mu_{x,F}(\delta)=F(x)+dF_x.$$

Does this work? Is there a more elegant or standard way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, $C_x^0$ doesn't have additive inverses. I would have made $C_x^0$ be equivalence classes on functions, where $f \equiv g$ if they are identical on some open set containing $x$. But I think that forces a metric $d$ to be the limit of small neighborhoods in the first place, not something you could take a limit of.

Comment: @aschepler Right. We could settle on $C^0_x$ just being a topological space and not a TVS. But I agree it would be best if it were a more natural space.

Comment: @aschepler Maybe the equivalence classes could be used, and instead of a single metric, we use a family of metrics and a topology induced by them?

Comment: I don't see how multiple metrics could be well-defined on those equivalence classes.

Comment: @aschepler I see. Perhaps it would be better to forget equivalence classes, just consider $C^0(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$, and use a family of metrics.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4375527/169085 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4432906/169085

Comment: Two more comments: 1) There is a more quantitative version of your first suggestion for a natural definition (which is equivalent to definition with limits of ratios): $F(x+h)-F(x) = \Lambda h + o_{|h|\to 0}(|h|)$ (which uses not only topology but normed topology), is this unsatisfactory?

Comment: 2) If the derivative is separated to the RHS, there is a problem with directions; depending on the direction of the vector on the LHS different values will be obtained, so on the RHS somehow the directions would need to be explicitly declared (as it is done for directional derivatives).

Comment: @AlpUzman But notice how my proposed idea under "Update" does not require specifying directions, just taking smaller neighborhoods of $x$. I'm looking for something like this, where we just have $dF_x=\lim_? <\text{something}>$, where the subtleties of the limit are captured by defining the topologies correctly.

Comment: @WillG I think your update works essentially; compare the Lipschitz jet formalism of Hirsch Pugh Shub (see their "Invariant Manifolds", p.26).

Comment: Though I should say according to their formalism the derivative would not be a limit but an affine representative (w/r/t a tangency relation on local functions; $f\sim g\iff d(f,g)=0$, where $d$ is almost your $d$).

Comment: It might be better to replace $\operatorname{dom}(f-g)$ with $\operatorname{dom}(f)\cap\operatorname{dom}(g)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_x^0 (\mathbb R^m)$ be the set of equivalence classes of continuous functions $f:U\to \mathbb R^m$ defined on a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, where two functions are equivalent if they agree on a neighborhood of $x$ (possibly smaller than the intersection of the two domains, in order to have an equivalence relation).

The algebra structure under pointwise operations is compatible with this equivalence relation, making $C_x^0(\mathbb R^m)$ an algebra over $\mathbb R$.

Linear maps $L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ are a subspace of $C_x^0(\mathbb R^m)$, with the embedding $A\mapsto[y\in\mathbb R^n \mapsto A(y-x)]$.

Let $[f]\in C_x^0(\mathbb R^n)$ and define :
$$\| [f]\| = \limsup_{y\to x}\frac{\|f(y)\|}{\|y-x\|} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \sup_{y\in B_\epsilon(x)\backslash\{0\}}\frac{\|f(y)\|}{\|y-x\|} $$

This is well defined on the equivalence classes, but may be infinite, so it does define a norm. To remedy this, we take :
$$d([f],[g]) = \min( 1,\|[f-g]\|)$$

This is well defined on equivalence classes and finite, but is still not a distance function, because, if $f$ is $C^1$ and has $f(x) = 0$ and $\text df(x) = 0$, then $d(f,0) =0$. But this allows us to characterize differentiable functions and define there derivative !

Explicitely, a function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if $\inf_{u \in L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)} d([f],[f(x) + u])  =0$ and its derivative is the $u \in L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ for which this minimum is reached.

Comment: Hm, I think your definition of $\|[f]\|$ needs to have the $g$ removed? Perhaps the definition given is actually of $\|[f]-[g]\|$?

Comment: Indeed, that was a typo as I first thought about defining $\|[f]-[g]\|$ before realizing that the $[g]$ was superfluous there. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Actually I think we want $f(y)-f(x)$ in the numerator.

Comment: Both options are actually ok. In my example, if $f(x)\neq g(x)$ then $d(f,g) = 1$, while if put $f(y)-f(x)$ in the numerator we would get $d(f,g) = 0$. In the latter case, we have that $f$ is differentiable if there is $u$ linear such that $d(f,u) = 0$, while we had to take $u$ affine in the case I presented.

Comment: This is interesting, I hadn't considered defining the "norm" using a limit. I think it's actually an infinite seminorm. Perhaps we could remedy the infinite behavior by restricted to functions for which it is finite (similar to what is done for bounded operators)? One concern I have is, does $d$ necessarily satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes, $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality. This follows from the fact that $\|\cdot\|$ does (including when some terms are infinite) and that $x\mapsto \min(1,x)$ is subadditive.