# Can we write the directional derivative $D_v f$ as $v[df]$?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f \in M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar function. Let also $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$. Finally, let $D_v f(p) = \frac{df(\gamma_v(t))}{dt} \vert_{t=0} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\gamma_v(t)) - f(p)}{t}$ (where $\gamma_v$ is any curve such that $\gamma_v(0)=p$ and $\gamma'_v(0) = v$) be the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction of $v$.

It is understood that the directional derivative above can be thought of as either the $1$-form $df$ acting on $v$ or the vector field $v$ acting on $f$ (where in the latter case we identify $v$ with the operator $v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$). Formally:

$$df \cdot v = v(f) = D_v f$$

This nearly creates a perfect symmetry between vector and covector fields. What seems to break the symmetry for me, is the notation. For instance why don't we usually see $v[df]$ on top of $v(f)$? More precisely, since there is nothing wrong with the way $v(f)$ is defined, why can't we also define a different action of $v$ (this time on $V^*$ instead of M $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) by using the standard isomorphism $\phi: V \rightarrow V^{**}$  that has the property $\phi(v)(\alpha) = \alpha(v)$ for all $\alpha$ in $V^*$. That way we could define $v[df]:= \phi(v)(df) = df \cdot v$ and conclude:

$$df \cdot v = v[df] = v(f) = D_v f$$

What I have in mind is that vectors are $(1,0)$ tensors or equivalently linear functionals acting on covectors (namely elements of $V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that "eat" covectors and spit out real numbers). The issue here is that $df \in V^*$ while $f$ is not.

Is there anything wrong with that line of thinking above? If not, what are the merits of the (seemingly) less symmetrical - and yet predominant in the literature - notation?

Comment: Should the definition of $D_vf(p)$ not be $\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}f(\gamma_v(t))$ ?

Comment: Two offhand comments: 1. The pairing $v[f]$ is linear (over functions) in $v$ but not in $f$; 2. If we identify $v$ with a partial derivative operator, $vf$ matches classical notation.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes thank you. That was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it boils down to if one prefers to view a vector as an element of
$\mathbb R^n$ or as a derivation that acts on functions at some $p\in M\,.$ We know that differential geometers don't make a difference between the two. Nevertheless, just to make this answer clearer, I shall write $\boldsymbol{v}$ for the former and $V$ for the latter:
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{v}=(v^1,...,v^n)^\top\,,\quad\quad V|_p=v^i\partial_i|_p\,.
\end{align}
As we know, $df=\partial_i f\,dx^i$ and (in traditional notation)
$$
df\cdot \boldsymbol{v}=v^i\partial_if=V(f)\,.
$$
Putting back the $p$ that was omitted for brevity we get a number in $\mathbb R:$
$$
df(p)\cdot\boldsymbol{v}=v^i\,\partial_i|_pf=V|_p(f)\,.
$$
The dot product on the left means that we contract the components of $df(p)\,,$ namely the covector $\partial_i|_pf$ with the components of $\boldsymbol{v}$ (the numbers $v^i$).
The term on the far right means that we apply the vector field
$$
V=v^i\partial_i
$$
to $f$ and evaluate this at $p\,.$ Both interpretations lead to the same expression in the middle.

There is also nothing wrong with the notation $\boldsymbol{v}[df]$ because $\boldsymbol{v}[df(p)]$ is the pairing of the vector $\boldsymbol{v}=(v^1,...,v^n)^\top$ with its dual $(\partial_1|_pf,...,\partial_n|_pf)\,.$

All of the above is still valid when the components of $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $V$ depend on $p\,.$

Comment: So you agree that it really depends on the chosen definition of the tangent space whether the expression $vf$ is even defined?

Comment: This is great thank you @Kurt G. Yes, this is exactly what I had in mind. Any idea, why the $V(f)$ notation is so prevalent in the literature? My understanding is that there is a great deal of utility, especially in physics to think of vectors as derivative operators which makes sense. That said, I do not think I have ever seen something akin to $v[df]$ anywhere in the literature before, not even just to illustrate a very nice - in my opinion - symmetry. Then again I am not a differential geometer.

Comment: @Pellenthor : I don't know why the $V(f)$ notation is prevalent in the literature. There is probably no deeper reason. An interesting related discussion with a nice answer by Andrew D. Hwang is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538719/differential-forms-without-derivatives). Have fun with differential geometry. It is a fantastic subject.